# CodeIssue project with roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

Is there a way to get a compilererror when someone write "new MyClass()" and MyClass Inherit from EntityBase. 
I like to stop developers to write this. Can I do this with a CodeIssue project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely!

This is exactly the sort of policy that CodeIssues are designed to handle.  You should be able to write a CodeIssue that inspects `ObjectCreationSyntax` nodes.  The code to check the inheritance looks something like (not near a compiler at the moment, so this is from memory):

```
var entityBaseType = document.Project.GetCompilation(cancellationToken).GetTypeByMetadataName("FullyQualifiedTypeName.EntityBase");
var typeInfo = document.GetSemanticModel(cancellationToken).GetTypeInfo(node);
if (typeInfo.Type.BaseType.Equals(entityBaseType))
{
    return new CodeIssue(...);
}

return null;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have trouble figuring out how to inspect ObjectCreationSyntax. There is so little examples out there.

Comment: Take a look at the "Working with Semantics" walkthrough that comes with the Roslyn CTP.  It has several examples of using the SemanticModel to answer these sorts of questions.

Comment: Where has the `CodeIssue` class gone? seems they changed the name.